# Bind to a non-DOM ui element

Tags: knockout.js, fabricjs

I'm using the fantastic knockout.js to bind ViewModel properties to the DOM. Now, part of my GUI is rendered on a canvas element. I use fabric.js to draw the elements on the canvas. Since these elements are not part of the dom (they are wrappers around canvas drawing methods), I cannot use knockout to bind to them. Nevertheless, I need to keep track of their position/color/label in the ViewModel.

I would think I could create a custom binding for each of the fabric primitive types and then bind them just like a dom node. However, a custom binding expects a DOM element as its first parameter. Secondly, I cannot (easily) add a binding programmatically. I need to be able to do this since I can't write the bindings in HTML.

I'm still thinking about this but I'm kinda stuck for the moment. Any ideas?

Comment: did you mind sharing a fiddle or other demo with source that has two way data binding? I can see the one way binding in fiddle in the answer below. Also, did you faced any other issues with fabric & knockout?

Comment: We didn't continue with fabric. We started using jointjs.com, which is svg-based (instead of canvas), allowing us to embed html inside the graphs and binding to those. I'm not recommending this exact library per se but something similar would be a goof choice I guess. It's a bit hard to quickly create a fiddle after all this time.

Comment: thanks for sharing. I'm creating a PoC with JointJS and knockoutjs. Can you share any fiddle for this? I'm looking into embedding html inside jointjs elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom bindings are implemented inside of computed observables, so that dependencies are tracked and the `update` functionality can be triggered again.

It sounds like for your functionality, you might want to consider using computed observables that track your objects, access dependencies, and make any necessary updates/api calls.

I haven't used fabric before until now, but here would be one take where you define a view model to represent a rectangle and create a computed to continually update the fabric object when any values change.

```
// create a wrapper around native canvas element (with id="c")
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var RectangleViewModel = function (canvas) {
  this.left = ko.observable(100);
  this.top = ko.observable(100);
  this.fill = ko.observable("red");
  this.width = ko.observable(100);
  this.height = ko.observable(100);

  this.rect = new fabric.Rect(this.getParams());
  canvas.add(this.rect);

  this.rectTracker = ko.computed(function () {
     this.rect.set(this.getParams());

     canvas.renderAll();      
  }, this);

};

RectangleViewModel.prototype.getParams = function () {
    return {
        left: +this.left(),
        top: +this.top(),
        fill: this.fill(),
        width: +this.width(),
        height: +this.height()
    };
};

var vm = new RectangleViewModel(canvas);

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Another brief idea, if you would rather keep some of the fabric/canvas calls out of your view model (I probably would). You could create a `fabric` binding that takes in an array of shapes to add to the canvas. You would also pass a handler that retrieves the params to pass to it. The binding would then create the shape, add it to the canvas, and then create a computed to update the shape on changes.  Something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fabric = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var shapes = valueAccessor(),
            canvas = new fabric.Canvas(element);

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(shapes, function (shape) {
            //create the new shape and initialize it
            var newShape = new fabric[shape.type](shape.params());
            canvas.add(newShape);

            //track changes to the shape (dependencies accessed in the params() function
            ko.computed(function () {
                newShape.set(this.params());
                canvas.renderAll();
            }, shape, {
                disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element
            });

        });
    }
};
```

You could place it on a canvas like:

```
<canvas data-bind="fabric: [ { type: 'Rect', params: rect.getParams }, { type: 'Rect', params: rect2.getParams } ]"></canvas>
```

At that point, the view model could be simplified quite a bit to just represent the rectangle's data.  Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/G6MGm/

Comment: The custom binding seems like a good approach. I would need to make the binding two-way (need to keep track of the shapes when they are dragged) but that seems easy enough with fabric events. I also noticed in your jsFiddle that, after I change the position in the textboxes, the 'click targets' of the drawn shapes seem to be incorrect, meaning that when I click/drag on the shapes, nothing happen. When I click next to the shape, I can drag it. Maybe fabric needs a refresh/redraw call or something.

Comment: @bertvh - yes- I didn't actually even realize you could click and drag /resize the shapes. I hadn't used fabric before that fiddle. You would definitely have to subscribe to fabric events in `init` and update the observables based on the data provided by the event.

Comment: @Niemeyer While not a complete solution, I accepted your answer since it really got me on the right trak. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue in my hobby project, http://simonlikesmaps.appspot.com ... I need to bind an array of waypoints onto a map and I cannot do it directly via KO because the waypoints are hidden inside OpenLayers SVG layers. So I use a subscribe function within this pattern:

First, a view model for the things you're displaying, for me waypoints, for you elements; roughly -

```
ElementViewModel = function(data) {
    this.position = ko.observable(data.position)
    this.label = ko.observable(data.label)
    this.color = ko.observable(data.color)
}
```

Second, a view model to hold a list of these things:

```
ElementListViewModel = function() {
    this.elements = ko.observableArray()
}
```

Then some logic to load your elements from your webservice into the view model, roughly:

```
var element_list = new ELementListViewModel()
ajax_success_function(ajax_result) {
   for (element in ajax_result) {
      element_list.elements.push(new ElementViewModel(element))
   }
}
```

It sounds like you will have this bit sorted; the aim is to end up with a list of elements held in an observableArray. You can then subscribe to it and do you Fabric work; there's a lot of pseudo-code in this next bit!

```
ElementListViewModel = function() {
    this.elements = ko.observableArray()
    this.elements.subscribe(function(new_elements) {
        // Remove everything from Fabric
        Fabric.removeEverything() // <!-- pseudo code alert!
        for (element in new_elements) {
            Fabric.addThing(convertToFabric(element))
        }
    }, this);
}
```

This isn't super-sophisticated, but does mean that whenever your data changes, and your list of elements change, those changes are immediately reflected in your canvas by KO calling the subscribe function. The 'synchronisation' between the new list of elements and what's already on the canvas is quite crude: simply destroy everything and re-render the entire list. This is OK for me with my waypoints, but might be too expensive for you.

Comment: Yeah.. that would indeed work for simple cases. However, there is no real binding going on. The items on my canvas are draggable by the user and I need the position to be synchronized to my viewmodels. I can't do that with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was interested to come across this question as I've also been trying to integrate fabric.js objects with the knockout model - I guess I'm reassured that there isn't a single obvious answer. Here is sample showing my latest thinking:
https://jsfiddle.net/whippet71/aky9af6t/
It has two-way data binding between DOM objects (text boxes) and the currently selected canvas object.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <canvas id="mycanvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>

<div class="form form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">X: <input data-bind="textInput: x" class="form-control"></div>
    <div class="form-group">Y: <input data-bind="textInput: y" class="form-control"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var jsonFromServer = [{"type":"rectangle","left":10,"top":100,"width":50,"height":50},{"type":"rectangle","left":85,"top":100,"width":50,"height":50},{"type":"circle","left":25,"top":250,"radius":50}];
var selectedObject;

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mycanvas');

for (var i=0; i<jsonFromServer.length; i++) {
    var thisShape = jsonFromServer[i];
    if (thisShape.type == 'rectangle') {
        var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            width: thisShape.width,
            height: thisShape.height,
            left: thisShape.left,
            top: thisShape.top,
            fill: 'blue'
        });
        canvas.add(rect);
    } else if (thisShape.type == 'circle') {
        var circle = new fabric.Circle({
            radius: thisShape.radius,
            left: thisShape.left,
            top: thisShape.top,
            fill: 'green'
        });
        canvas.add(circle);
    }
}
// Set first object as selected by default
selectedObject = canvas.getObjects()[0];
canvas.setActiveObject(selectedObject);


// A view model to represent the currently selected canvas object
function ShapeViewModel(initX, initY) {
    var self = this;

    self.x = ko.observable(initX);
    self.y = ko.observable(initY);
    // Create a computed observable which we subsribe to, to notice change in x or y position
    // Use deferred updates to avoid cyclic notifications
    self.position = ko.computed(function () {
        return { x: self.x(), y: self.y() };
    }).extend({ deferred: true });
}

var vm = new ShapeViewModel(selectedObject.left, selectedObject.top);
ko.applyBindings(vm);

// Function to update the knockout observable
function updateObservable(x, y) {
    vm.x(x);
    vm.y(y);
}

// Fabric event handler to detect when user moves an object on the canvas
var myHandler = function (evt) {
    selectedObject = evt.target;
    updateObservable(selectedObject.get('left'), selectedObject.get('top'));
}
// Bind the event handler to the canvas
// This does mean it will be triggered by ANY object on the canvas
canvas.on({ 'object:selected': myHandler, 'object:modified': myHandler }); 

// Make a manual subscription to the computed observable so that we can
// update the canvas if the user types in new co-ordinates
vm.position.subscribe(function (newPos) {
    console.log("new x=" + newPos.x + " new y=" + newPos.y);
    selectedObject.setLeft(+newPos.x); 
    selectedObject.setTop(+newPos.y);
    selectedObject.setCoords();
    canvas.renderAll();
    // Update server...
});
```

A few things to note:

- I create a ko.observable and make a manual subscription to it for the purpose of updating the fabric objects
- I set up a fabric event handler that updates the ko.observable on object selection/modification. I didn't have any need to bind to anything other than the currently selected object.
- I had to use deferred updates to avoid cyclic updates (fabric updates ko, which then notifies fabric...)

I'm very new to knockout so any comments/suggestions would be welcome.